# Another desktop's application showing on current desktop task bar

Tags: bash, kubuntu, google-chrome, kde, plasma

I'm having this annoying problem and need some help. The thing is, I have a script which opens/closes chrome windows to run some macros. In order to keep my desktop clean, I put this script on desktop 2. Even so, the chrome windows that were being opened keep doing so on desktop 1. To mitigate that problem, In used KDE windows options to always open chrome on desktop 2. But even then they keep showing on desktop 1 task manager, as you can see this in the printscreen, in which the konsole were opened on desktop 2 and yet is showing on desktop 1 taskbar.

Before someone asks, yes, I check on task manager options to only show tasks of current desktop.

So, there's a way to prevent the entries to showing up on task manager? Or, even better, to prevent windows opened by a konsole on another desktop to be opened on current desktop?
Thank you very much and have a nice day. =)

[image: Printscreen here]

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue of the task manager widget itself being set to display all windows from all desktops.

If this is the case, you will need to go into the task manager widget and select the options to "*Show only tasks from the current screen*" and "*Show only tasks from the current desktop*".
[image: Task manager widget settings]

Comment: Already tried it. When I click on the entry the screen goes to desktop 2 and the entry disappear of desktop 1 task manager until next time chrome opens.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to give Plasma Activities a try. It is much more flexible and robust, with many more behavioral options than the concept of virtual desktops. For instance, when you create a new Activity, and then go into it's settings, you will see a tab entitled "Switching". The first item under this section will be a checkbox offering to "remember the current virtual desktop for each activity". This may well lad to the behavior that you wanted to do.

Activities are much more powerful than the idea of virtual desktops, and combining both adds a lot of synergies that either on its own probably could not do as well. That is, once they are understood. Good luck.

See also: [How to Setup KDE Activities](https://www.datamation.com/open-source/how-to-setup-kde-activities.html)